# what is the technique of moving straight background tileSprite in phaser

Tags: phaser-framework, vertical-scrolling

This code is for tilling the background from top to bottom. 
However, I would like to tilling the background straight to the camera view. what technique I need to use for achieving it?

```
preload: function() {
    this.game.load.image('road', 'assets/images/road.png');
},
create: function() {
    this.game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 1136, 640);
    this.road = this.game.add.tileSprite(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY,    this.game.width, this.game.height, 'road');
    this.road.anchor.setTo(0.5); 
},
update: function() {
    this.road.tilePosition.y +=1;
}
```

Here is the example of the tilling background I have found in this game http://www.nickjr.com/paw-patrol/games/paw-pups-save-the-day/.

[background image tile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug99M.png)

Can anyone give me a clue to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure the tiling sprite is the correct way to do this, you may be better to do this using a standard sprite sheet animation.

I used this method for the game here: 
[image]
http://www.nicktoons.co.uk/microsite/dribbletricks/3fo5mu

The sprite sheet is [image: sprite sheet]

So essentially it is just a sprite with animation set to loop. Here, as the background is symmetrical I duplicated the sprite and for the RHS of the pitch scaled its x value to -1 so that the sprite sheet/file sizes were smaller allowing for more frames.

Comment: Thanks you the way you guided me. I really appreciated it.